# Opening other element on focus on current one Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

In my controller I have input box and a div with text.
By default div is set to display:none

I want to make div visible by focusing on input box.
Is it possible to do with angular.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (No need to set you div display:none, initally showDiv is false and your div will be hidden):

```
 <body ng-controller="myController" ng-init="showDiv=false">
    <input type="text" ng-focus="showDiv=true">
    <div ng-show="showDiv"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yea Angular makes it super easy without even having to write anything in controller, here's an example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/OqLpGxWwfPaBTVdTBYDy?p=preview

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-hide="show" />
    <button ng-click="show = !show">Show / Hide</button>
  </body>
```

Obviously you could make yours on a hover instead of a click but you get the idea.